# Angular2 typescript with nested json response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm working on a project which has front end app in Angular. After sending a request on my back end API, I have a nested JSON response as we can see on screen shot attached.

My question is about know how to process it with typescript and display it on view.
(Let me remind you that my goal is to create table tree in view)

[json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOR93.png)

Comment: Please be more specific, and don't use images when sharing code. Please see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My question is about know how to iterate on nested json response  to display it's data on my view like  table tree

Comment: That's a too broad question. It can be done with loops, third part libraries etc. Also, where should it be displayed? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am getting the response using observable and have learned to cast the first node with TYPESCRIPT .it should be displayed on view(HTML) this is what i'am trying                                                                                       getListcomptes(idclient: number): Observable< Compte[]>  {

        const urlcomptes=`${this.postUrlComptes}/${idclient}`;
         return this.authHttp.get(urlcomptes)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                var resultcomptes = response.json();
                return resultcomptes;
            });



    }

Comment: json respoonse look like this :                                                                  "Premium": {
            "ingroup": [
                {
                    "id": 31165,
                    "login": "100000@27624",

                },
                {
                    "id": 31168,
                    "login": "100000@26380",

                }
            ],
            "outgroup": [
                {
                    "id": 31169,
                    "login": "1507@1984",

                }
            ]
        }

Comment: In  you template you use `*ngFor` on the array you want to iterate over.  An example `*ngFor="let item of Premium.ingroup"`

Comment: the fact is that I'am trying to create and tree  hierarchy(like  my json data) so how  Iterate  on this nested json to reach my goal

Answer (score 0):

> My question is about know how to process it with typescript and display it on view.

There are two questions here :

> how to process it with typescript

Angular HTTP will parse the JSON.

If you are not using HTTP you can use JSON.parse

> display it on view.

Use angular's data binding.

## Docs

- Data binding : https://angular.io/guide/quickstart
- Angular HTTP : https://angular.io/api/http/Http
- JSON.parse : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse